# How can I draw texture and gradient as a background in python image using PIL?

Tags: python, python-3.5, python-imaging-library

I am using black as a background as of now. I want to have a white and black mixed gradient color in the background of an image.

Below is the code that I'm using as of now. Please help.

```
import PIL
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
font = ImageFont.truetype("MelmaCracked.ttf", 25)
img = Image.new("RGBA", (500,400), (0,0,0,0))
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
draw.text((0,0), "This is a test", (255,255,255,1), font=font)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
img.save("test.png")
```

I want to create a gradient of white and black in background of my image.

In below question, manually gradient is created.
[Plot gradients using PIL in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30608035/plot-gradients-using-pil-in-python)

In above answer two gradients are created, one for circle and one for rectangle, but I'm looking for something through which we can tweak all of the gradient types with some change of code.

And any other alternative to achieve the same purpose.

P.S. I'm using Python 3.5

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plot gradients using PIL in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30608035/plot-gradients-using-pil-in-python)

Comment: Yes that's there but it is not a great solution, I need to implement a code through which after tweaking some part of code or values, gradient type changes. And we have n number of gradient types.